# How can I block ssh access to users with pam?

Tags: sshd, pam, access-control

I've been poking around `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for the last week or so, trying to figure out how to block ssh access to all users besides myself.

My goal is for it to be impossible for all users except to me to login via ssh, and for my account to be accessible through 2fa+password or key based auth. I currently have the later half of that working, but I can't figure out how to block all users except myself. I already have the lines I'd expect to work in my `sshd_config`:

```
AllowUsers me
DenyUsers *
```

But when I try and ssh into another user account (for example, `fred`), it still prompts me with `Password:`. I also tried adding the following line at the top of my `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
auth      required   pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup ssh
```

And having only myself in the `ssh` group.

What am I doing wrong to block all users besides myself from ssh access? I have to use PAM because that's how my 2fa works.

Comment: You can use `/etc/security/access.conf` file to have more control who should and who shouldn't have access to your server.

Comment: You are prompted for a password but can you actually log in?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I can't login, but it concerns me that a prompt is being sent. That also makes it possible to find the usernames of all the users, which I wouldn't like to be possible.

Comment: Don't you need `requisite` rather than `required`?  And the behaviour is a good one - to prevent the information leakage of which users are worth attacking.

Comment: @mrc02_kr I'd like to only prohibit SSH access, not stop access entirely.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm not sure if this is the desired behavior, but now for any user besides myself (including non-existant users) it'll output `Permission denied: (publickey,keyboard-interactive)`.

Comment: @thesecretmaster 1. SSH prompt for password won't allow anybody to discover every username in your system. Password prompt is displayed no matter what user name you specify (existing or not existing). 
2. I don't know why are you talking about stopping access  to SSH entirely, but I suppose you haven't even read man page of  access.conf.

Comment: @mrc02_kr You'd be right. I didn't rtfm, but I did read the large explanitory comment in that file. I think that I'm all set now. I'll write a self answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `access.conf` to prevent ssh, and only ssh, logins does not work.  However, it can be accomplished by using `pam_access` with another config file.

Firstly, PAM must be configured to use pam_access.  It might not be by default.  There should be a line with `account required pam_access.so` in the `sshd` PAM config, likely via the `password-auth` configuration file, which the sshd config will likely include.

On Fedora, `authselect` can be used to enable a PAM configuration to use pam_access:

```bsh
sudo authselect enable-feature with-pamaccess
```

At this point one might think access could be prevented with a line in `access.conf` such as:

```
-:username:sshd
```

This does not work to prevent *username* from access when using the service `sshd`.  The reason is this bit from the pam_access manpage:

> ... or PAM service names in case of **non-networked** logins.

Since ssh is a network login (PAM's `RHOST` field is defined), the service name is not used.  Only the remote host name, IP address, network group, etc. are used.

This manpage is not entirely accurate, as the PAM service name is only used if  the login is non-networked **and non-tty**.  Local logins, e.g. at the console login prompt, desktop greeter, or running sudo, will use the associated tty or X display rather than the service name.

Effectively, the service name is only used for background logins, like with atd or crond.  So you can't block just ssh this way as there is no way in access.conf to filter ssh vs anything else.

### TL;DR

One can restrict all remote logins, not just with ssh but with all other services too, via:

```
+:username:LOCAL
-:username:ALL
```

To only apply to ssh, PAM must be configured to use a different access.conf file for sshd.  Add a line like this to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, probably just before the line that contains `account include password-auth`:

```
account    required     pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-sshd.conf
```

Now create `/etc/security/access-sshd.conf` with access controls that will only apply to ssh logins.  Examples:

```
# Don't allow user 'username' access
-:username:ALL

# Only allow user 'trusted' access and no one else
-:ALL EXCEPT trusted:ALL

# Only allow user 'username' when they are coming from localhost
+:username:127.0.0.1 ::1
-:username:ALL
```

Note that using `localhost` instead of the numeric IPv4 and IPv6 address should work, but didn't for me.