# Prohibit sudo commands when run from a SSH session

Tags: terminal, sudo

Is there a way to prohibit sudo commands when issued from a SSH session specifically, while allowing them from local terminals?

I looked at the [`sudoers`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) and [`sudo.conf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudo.conf.5.html) man pages and search for "terminal", without success.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387781/how-can-i-block-ssh-access-to-users-with-pam) may have something useful.

Comment: `pam_securetty` looks promising. Thank you for the hint, I thought that PAM would provide the solution rather than sudo itself.

Comment: That sounds right to me; AFAIK, `sudo` does not have *conditional privileges*, and `sudo` does use PAM for authentication. And so it would *seem* to be a matter of adding a condition to the `auth` condition - something like `TTY !+ pts`? Very interesting question though - pls let know when you find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking at the wrong tool.

sudo limits access based on who can do what.

If you don't want to grant x access (such as root) over ssh, then don't allow that user to remotely log int via ssh.  This is where this would get implemented, as far as I see the architecture.  Root access can specifically be banned via ssh, that's been there forever.  But that's attached to the root account. Sudo expands who can do root'ish things, and can document who has that kind of access.

If you don't want sudo to be available by ssh, then don't allow anyone with sudo access (to do y, or z) to be able to remotely log in.

Basically, this is in line with the "do one thing, and do it well" architecture of Unix/Linux.

- sudo -> document who can be blamed for actions
- ssh  -> allow secure remote access

Now, you may be able to set up PAM to do what you want, but that's not where I'd go first.  I wouldn't want to have to make that work correctly and provably.  If you are going down that road, I'd do some reading (suggestion:https://www.tiltedwindmillpress.com/product/pam/), and I suspect you'll come back to my suggestion.

Cheers

Mike

Comment: SSH login as root is already forbidden, but login as regular user should be possible. Only sudo-ing from SSH sessions should be prohibited, while locally allowed for a user. PAM looks promising, I'll look into that. Thank you so far.

Comment: "`don't allow that user to remotely log int via ssh`" There are still useful things a user might accomplish over SSH without using `sudo`, so that doesn't strike me as a useful solution. But perhaps I'm missing your actual point here??

Comment: I do think if this is actually what you want, then PAM is where you need to go, but I don't understand why you'd trust the user at the console, but not remotely.  If I needed to do that, I'd have two usernames for that actual human:  mike_local and mike.  I'd put them in the same group that includes only them, and then only add mike_local to sudo access.  But I'd then wonder what the "remote mike" would be doing, looking at things, running things, etc. I guess if I trusted the actual human, I'd just be making sure that it had to be that actual human when coming through via ssh (like 2 factor?)

Comment: I also would like to know what you actually do, and how you accomplished this with PAM (once you're sure its correct and secure).  PAM has always struck me as a tool similar to nitroglycerin.  Effective, but also easy to inadvertently cause really spectacular blast sites that include the tool user.